# Fetch Data from API NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

Unable to fetch data from api, want to fetch and display in browser.

The stocks API is designed to return errors sometimes

here is the code
app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const stocks = require('./stocks')

const app = express()
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))

app.get('/stocks', async (req, res) => {
  const stockSymbols = await stocks.getStocks()
  res.send({ stockSymbols })
})

app.get('/stocks/:symbol', async (req, res) => {
  const { params: { symbol } } = req
  const data = await stocks.getStockPoints(symbol, new Date())
  res.send(data)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running!'))
```

stock.js, in this file stock data will fetch from this file.
this file code supposed to be remain same bc this is the main api.

```
/* PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE AT ALL! */
const stocks = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'FB', 'EA', 'IBM']

const HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60
const TIME_RANGE = HOUR * 10
const VALUE_RANGE_MIN = 10
const VALUE_RANGE_MAX = 100
const FAILUE_RATE = 0.1

function getTimestamps (timestamp, resolution) {
  const timestamps = []
  for (let idx = 0; idx < resolution; idx++) {
    timestamps.push(timestamp - (resolution - idx - 1) / resolution * TIME_RANGE)
  }
  return timestamps
}

function calculate (cyclesPerDay, cycleOffset, timestamp) {
  return scaleValue(Math.sin(timestamp / (HOUR * 24) * Math.PI * cyclesPerDay + cycleOffset))
}

function scaleValue (value) {
  const diff = VALUE_RANGE_MAX - VALUE_RANGE_MIN
  return VALUE_RANGE_MIN + diff * ((value + 1) / 2)
}

function strSum (str) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(str, char => char.charCodeAt()).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

function getSeries (stockName, timestamps) {
  const sum = strSum(stockName)
  const cyclesPerDay = sum % 11 + 1 / 4
  const cycleOffset = Math.PI * (sum % 10) / 10
  return timestamps.map(calculate.bind(null, cyclesPerDay, cycleOffset))
}

module.exports = {
  async getStocks () {
    return stocks
  },
  async getStockPoints (stockName, timestamp) {
    if (Math.random() < FAILUE_RATE) {
      throw new Error('Failed to generate stock data')
    }
    if (!stocks.includes(stockName)) {
      throw new Error(`Uknown stock ${stockName}`)
    }
    const timestamps = getTimestamps(+timestamp, 10)
    return getSeries(stockName, timestamps).map((value, idx) => ({
      value,
      timestamp: timestamps[idx]
    }))
  }
}
```

script.js code

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

function drawLine (start, end, style) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = style || 'black'
  ctx.moveTo(...start)
  ctx.lineTo(...end)
  ctx.stroke()
}

function drawTriangle (apex1, apex2, apex3) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(...apex1)
  ctx.lineTo(...apex2)
  ctx.lineTo(...apex3)
  ctx.fill()
}

drawLine([50, 50], [50, 550])
drawTriangle([35, 50], [65, 50], [50, 35])

drawLine([50, 550], [950, 550])
drawTriangle([950, 535], [950, 565], [965, 550])
```

html file to fetch data from stock api and display in chart shape with timeline.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>task</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <span class="spinner"></span>
</div>

<canvas id="chart" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>

<canvas id="2d" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
<script src="scripts.js" defer>

    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched the solution but couldn't found the appropriate solution for that so now im posting this question to get exact answer

Comment: I think we'd need to see `scripts.js`

Comment: @Nick  script.js code  `const canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

function drawLine (start, end, style) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = style || 'black'
  ctx.moveTo(...start)
  ctx.lineTo(...end)
  ctx.stroke()
}

function drawTriangle (apex1, apex2, apex3) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(...apex1)
  ctx.lineTo(...apex2)
  ctx.lineTo(...apex3)
  ctx.fill()
}

drawLine([50, 50], [50, 550])
drawTriangle([35, 50], [65, 50], [50, 35])

drawLine([50, 550], [950, 550])
drawTriangle([950, 535], [950, 565], [965, 550])
`